# Two diodes at the inputs of op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

Often in power supply schematics they use two diodes at the inputs of op-amps:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGut5U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

What's the purpose of having two diodes at an op-amp's inputs?

Comment: Limit the input swing when the opamp bottoms out to speed up the recovery?

Comment: @winny For poor old opamps?

Comment: Pretty much. Also, whoever did the schematic is not within his or hers right mind when negative voltages are pointing up and positives down and C13 is “103”. But sure, if you look at older application notes for opamps, you should be able to find your antiparallel diodes there.

Comment: Pretty sloppy work, considring the LM234 is a 3-terminal current source. I guess it's supposed to be an LM324.

Comment: It seems that the diodes have a effect of making the voltages at inverting and non inverting terminals of the Op-amp same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because op-amps should have near 0 voltage difference between the inputs. The diodes are there so that a large voltage difference doesn't de-bias the input stage by causing the internal transistors to operate in non-linear modes. Sometimes those diodes are internal to the op-amp. Basically just input protection diodes.

That's one of the (many) reasons you don't want to use op-amps as comparators. Comparators will never have those diodes, while sometimes op-amp do have them, meaning that they will draw a lot of current and clamp when the input(s) swing.

Answer (score 0):

These antiparallel diodes at opamp input will avoid a phase reversal effect at output.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain in more detail how the diodes achieve this.